# Use jest "watch mode" with nx test (nx CLI)

Tags: jestjs, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I have an app that was generated with [Nx CLI](https://nx.dev/web/guides/cli). I can run tests for this app with Jest using the the command `nx test myApp`. This works fine. However, I would like to use Jest's ["watch mode"](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#--watch). when running my tests, and can't figure out how to achieve this. Nx's documentation says simply:

> To run unit tests for your application:
>
> `nx test myapp`

I have been unable to find any more detailed documentation for this command, or how to add any other options/flags to it. Is there anyway to use watch mode with `nx test`?

Answer (score 8):

> TL;DR: `yarn affected:test --all --parallel --maxParallel 10 --watch` should work.

`nx test` actually runs `ng test` which in its turn is using the `@nrwl/jest:jest` builder that has a `--watch` option *(in addition to some other jest specific options)*. You can see all the options by running `nx test --help`

**Warning:** If you have multiple apps/libs in your repository, this will only watch your default project's tests.

If you really want to watch all your projects tests, you will have to run:

`yarn affected:test --all --parallel --maxParallel 10 --watch`

- `--all` we need this otherwise, this will not run tests on projects that you "affect" after running the command
- `--parallel` because you want to run all the tests in parallel, otherwise this will only watch the first project in the list
- `--maxParallel` because the default limit is 3 so if you have more than 3 projects, it will only watch tests for the 3 first projects

Answer (score 2):

A simple command to run test for your applications with watch is

`nx test <packageName> --watch`

If you want to run test for a specific file in watch mode.

`nx test <packageName> --testFile=<fileName> --watch`

If you want to clear cache

`nx test <packageName> --clearCache`

Answer (score 0):

If all your projects are using jest, there should be no issues with simply running:

`jest --watch`

Running adding a script for that and running it in the root directory works pretty well for me!